# Is it possible to deploy a Django website using HostGator shared Linux Web Hosting?

Tags: python, django

I am looking for a solution, to deploy my Django app on my Unlimited Linux Shared Hosting Plan on Hostgator.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible ? Yes

Is it recommendable? No

as it says on the same hostgator page:

> While it is possible to install Django on HostGator servers, it is not a supported application

This means that hostgator is not designed to host django. My recommendation would be:

If it is a simple project: Use Heroku

If it's a project that might later become something bigger: Use google app engine (google cloud) or Elastic beanstalk(AWS)